# How to get random documents using spring mongorepository?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongo, spring-mongodb

Lets assume the following structure:

A user class:

```
public class User {

@Id
String id;
String name;
//...

}
```

The users repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

List<User> findByRandom(); // this method signature does not exist but would do what I intend to do

}
```

A user controller:

```
@Component
public class UserController {

    private UserRepository users;

      @Autowired
      public UserController(
          UserRepository users) {
        this.users= users;
      }

public List<User> getRandomUsers() {
return(users.findByRandom()); // limit is missing here
}

        }
```

How would one achieve to receive random documents out of a structure like this.
Having a field with a random value on the document would not be a desired solution, since the values should always be random (e.g. if I hit the random int value 4 and receive the x following items, those would always be the same). Having to query x times is also not prefered, since this would be too heavy load.
Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance,

Codehai

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) stage:

Via Spring-Data (from v2.0 onwards):

```
SampleOperation matchStage = Aggregation.sample(5);
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(sampleStage);
AggregationResults<OutType> output = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "collectionName", OutType.class);
```

Directly through the Java driver:

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.*;
users.aggregate(Arrays.asList(sample(5)));
```

Comment: can you give a more detailed answer, since the aggregate method seems not to be part of the org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository base methods ( throws can't resolve method) and I am having problems finding an example over the web

Comment: I'm sorry, it's getting late here - I somehow hadn't seen the "Spring" part so I initially just gave the "standard Java driver" answer...

Comment: Sadly, this only works with spring data 2.0 upwards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35976725/random-documents-from-mongodb-using-spring-data